# How do you do accidentals (eg. E♭) in solfège (Do Re Mi)?

Tags: theory, notation, scales, solfege

I only ever learned the basics of the major scale syllables, mostly from the "Doe, a deer" song.

In C Major,

- Do - C
- Re - D
- Mi - E
- Fa - F
- Sol - G
- La - A
- Ti (or Si) - B
- Do - C

So how do you augment this framework with the black keys?

I suppose here, I'm referring to a "Fixed Do" anchored to middle C, but I think (hope) it applies to a "Movable Do" as well, relative to the current tonic.

Comment: If this is already covered elsewhere on the site, I couldn't find it by searching for "accidental solfage", so I felt a canonical question was in order.

Comment: There are a few different traditions here. While there are accidental systems for fixed-do solfege, my impression is that they are not actually used much for singing. Moveable-do is different. Do you want answers to focus on all the permutations in use, or do you want to focus on a specific method and application, like sung fixed-do?

Comment: Well, hmmm. Specifically, I want enough background to understand the distinction between Ti Ta and Te mentioned in [this answer](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/28518/1344). But more broadly, I'd want something actually currently used rather than more academic/historical (although that's welcome, too. I loves me some history).

Comment: That answer is a bit confusing if you don’t have solfège background. Essentially it’s trying to tell you that B, B♭, and B♯ all refer to the same scale degree, differing only in color. In fixed-do, you’d call it *si,* and in moveable-do, you’d call it *ti* or *te* depending on whether it’s flat. (Solfège mostly ignores B♯ and C♭.)

Answer (score 5):

The most standard convention I know of is to change the vowel to "i" for sharping and "e" for flatting.  The exception is when flatting "re", in which case you go to "ra".

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks right for moveable do, but fixed do has different common practices.

Comment: I think in fixed do, there are no alterations (i.e., C, Cb, and C# are all do), right?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I think that’s the most common way to do it, although there are [chromatic variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solfège#Chromatic_variants) of fixed do that use alternate syllables.